# How to code retry policy for port in server side to listen client request?

Tags: java, algorithm, sockets, http

I am writing **HTTP WEB SERVER** code. In the mean while I have to code retry policy on using port, so that on that port server can listen client's request.

**Normal Code:**

```
serversocket = new ServerSocket(ServerSettings.port);
```

It throws Exception, if `ServerSettings.port` is not free.

Now, I want to add retry policy, if `ServerSettings.port` is not free, try other ports. For that I write one code, and code is a s follows,

**Updated Code:**

```
   try {
            serversocket = new ServerSocket(ServerSettings.port);
        } catch (IOException io) {
            try {
                ServerSettings.port += 505;
                serversocket = new ServerSocket(ServerSettings.port);
            } catch (IOException io1) {
                try {
                    ServerSettings.port += 505;
                    serversocket = new ServerSocket(ServerSettings.port);
                } catch (IOException io2) {
                    log.info(new Date() + "Problem occurs in binding port");
                }
            }
        }
```

But above one shows poor coding skills, and not professional one.

How can I write retry policy for ports in a professional way, so that server can listen on that port?

Comment: Maybe wrap it in a `while-loop`, checking a `boolean` type variable, that tells if the port is is free? After the creation of the object: `portIsFree = true`, and the condition to try again will be `portIsFree == false`

Comment: @GuyDavid What is the method to check wheather port is free or not ?

Comment: `ServerSocket` will throw the exception if it failed to use the given port, so it will not execute any code afterwards- it will pass the line that sets `portIsFree = true;`, and will jump to the `catch` section. The loop will continue, since `portIsFree` is still set to `false`.

Comment: How is the client going to know what other port the server is using if the first one fails? Until you decide that, it's pointless to worry about how to code the server end. Most likely you shouldn't even have a 'retry policy' at all: just reserve the port for the server, and if it isn't available, exit and let the operator deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, I think this will work (Correct me if there are any syntax typos):

```
ServerSocket serversocket; 
boolean foundPort = false;

while (!foundPort)
{
     try {
          serversocket = new ServerSocket(ServerSettings.port); // If this fails, it will jump to the `catch` block, without executing the next line
          foundPort = true;
     }
     catch (IOException io) {
          ServerSettings.port += 505;
     }
}
```

You could wrap it in a function, and instead of `foundPort = true;`, you would return the socket object.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I ahve one more problem, please help me in that, and the link is as follows, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16395396/how-to-add-feature-of-shutdown-in-http-web-server/16395478?noredirect=1#16395478