# How to add feature of "SHUTDOWN" in MultiThreaded Http Web Server code

Tags: java, multithreading, http

I am writing a *HTTP THREAD-POOLED WEB SERVER* code. I made my code at my best. It works fine also.

But there is one problem, whenever I want to shut down my server, I have to use `CTRL + C`. But that is a bad way to shut down.

I think a lot, to add shutdown feature in my code. But I am unable to do that.

Please help me to add this feature, give any suggestion to do that, I will definitely code that.

**EDIT NO. 1**

One method that I think is to make one thread that is only listening STDIN input given by keyboard. Whenever it gets "SHUTDOWN". It calls `ThreadPol.shutdown()`. This way I can achieve this goal.

Is this a right method ? If yes, please help me to implement this.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your problem, what is the exact problem with your actual method? How do you want to improve it?

Comment: My problem is, whenever I want to shutdown my HTTP server, I have to press CTRL+C, that is very method method. Now I want to implement this shutdown feature. Please help me in that. I think you understand my prolem.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: @oe.elvik Sorry I can not post my code because of some reasons. But I can explain the workflow of my code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Daemonize a Java Program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534648/how-to-daemonize-a-java-program)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

[ThreadPoolExecuto.shutdownNow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.

Comment: I didn't understand, what you said. How/where can I implement this.

Comment: where ever you write thi line and when executes the system will shutdown

Comment: I know above command, and I know one more method that will do this. But I didn't understand where I put this code.

Comment: Is there any GUI to operate ??